# What are the most controversial non-wiki posts on stack overflow?

Tags: discussion

What are the most controversial non-wiki posts on stack overflow?

Comment: Why do I get the feeling that you've already got a list of them? ;-)

Comment: yeah Im formatting it at the moment :p

Comment: How are you determining controversiality? min(upvotes, downvotes)?

Comment: down > up * 0.5 ordered by up desc ... so its not really fully accurate but kind of typical

Comment: @waffles, just curious, why did you limit this to non-wiki posts?

Comment: @Popular in general I like to exclude them from my queries, people are  a lot more likely to downvote on wiki stuff anyway cause there is no cost

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [my shot](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/1)

By far the most controversial non-wiki post on SO is Joel's famous [IOC answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871405/why-do-i-need-an-ioc-container-as-opposed-to-straightforward-di-code/871420#871420). Nothing else comes close.

Comment: I have been looking through the list, I think the query does a good job.

Comment: It is pretty hard to beat that.

Comment: @Sam Saffron: great work!

Comment: I wish you had included the OP name so I could quickly check if any of those were mine.

Comment: That's it Shog9, I'm writing spShog9 for formatting link lists

Comment: FYI: spShog9 is alive http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248764/formatting-link-lists-using-tsql

Comment: this query is no longer working on stackoverflow site, it times out