# What is the most controversial answer on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, answers

Controversial is defined as:

- large number of upvotes and downvotes
- large number of comments

If you can think of extra criteria, feel free to edit the question.

Comment: Is this meant as a joke...? Because the same question has been asked, and answered, quite recently, hasn't it? The top downvoted answer has something like 40 downvotes.

Comment: @Questions - he's looking for controversial, not most downvoted.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406760/whats-your-most-controversial-programming-opinion

Comment: How is this different from [What are the most controversial non-wiki posts on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12756/what-are-the-most-controversial-non-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow)?

Comment: @Kenny This doesn't specify "Non-wiki"

Comment: Would it be acceptable to update this question to say "Stack Exchange network" instead of "Stack Overflow" to make it on-topic? Or would that be too broard. I assume this was asked when there was only Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 9):

An [answer to Why do I need an IoC container as opposed to straightforward DI code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871405/why-do-i-need-an-ioc-container-as-opposed-to-straightforward-di-code/871420#871420) has +156/-169 with 43 comments. I think it's an especially good candidate for "most controversial" since up- and down-votes are rather balanced.

More controversies:

```
select postid, up_count, -down_count, comm_count
from
  (select postid, count(id) as up_count from votes where votetypeid = 2
     group by postid) as u
  INNER JOIN
  (select postid, count(id) as down_count from votes where votetypeid = 3
     group by postid) as d
  USING (postid)
  INNER JOIN
  (select postid, count(id) as comm_count from comments
     group by postid) as c
  USING (postid)
where up_count > 5 and down_count > 5 and comm_count > 5
order by log(up_count) + log(down_count) - log(1 + abs(up_count-down_count)) +
         log(comm_count) desc
limit 100;
```

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how you define it. By pure numbers, I'd say it would have to be [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164432/what-real-life-bad-habits-has-programming-given-you/164556#164556) (now 'deleted') -- 1172 up, 107 down, and 105 comments.

But nobody was arguing about it.

Comment: Yeah, but the reason for those downvotes wasn't controversy over the answer, it was a tug of war to try and keep the vote total at 256.

Comment: ah, my claim to fame...

Answer (score 2):

This [answer to Does Python have “private” variables in classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1641305/12287457) has a remarkably balanced score of +182/-173 at the time of writing.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174892/what-is-the-most-spectacular-way-to-shoot-yourself-in-the-foot-with-c/174901#174901) is +20/-65, and has the lowest vote total on SO.